# How to print to Json File. Prints to Terminal, Opens Json. No data transfer

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup

How do you solve for getting this output to print to a structured json?

This code creates the json file, and prints the response in my terminal. But does not send the structured data to the json file.

```
from seoanalyzer import analyze
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
site = 'http://www.microblink.com'

output = analyze(site, follow_links=False)

with open("output.json", "w", encoding = 'utf-8') as file:

    print(output)
```

//
Sample output:

```
{'pages': [{'url': 'http://www.microblink.com', 'title': 'microblink: ai-driven technology for solving real life problems', 'description': 'create amazing experiences, verify users at scale and automate your document-based workflow with ai tech built for a remote world.', 'word_count': 659, 'keywords': [(17, 'identity'), (13, 'verification'), (9, 'microblink'), (8, 'technology'), (8, 'industries'), (7, 'contact'), (6, 'document'), (6, 'blog'), (5, 'resources'), (5, 'experiences'), (5, 'customers')], 'bigrams': Counter({'identity verification': 10, 'sign up': 3, 'your customers': 3, 'verification in': 3, 'able to': 3, 'we re': 3, 'identity identity': 2, 'verification document': 2, 'document verification': 2, 'verification identity': 2, 'identity document': 2,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just opened the json file with `with open("output.json", "w", encoding = "utf-8") as file` without writing anything to it.

To save your data to the json file you need to dump the data into the json file.

```
with open("output.json", "w", encoding = 'utf-8') as file:

    print(output)
    json.dump(output, file)
```

For that to work you need to `import json` in your code.

Comment: That worked, thank you!

What is the best way to then structure it after it arrives in the json?

Comment: Glad it helped. What do you mean by structuring it? Saving it in a specific format to the json file? For custom indendation you can pass an argument to the indent parameter of the `dump` function. 

`json.dump(output, file, indent=4)`

Comment: The data comes as a string. And I’d like it to be in a more readable format when it gets to the json.